# FileSystemWatcher Events Not Firing

Tags: c#, winforms, filesystemwatcher

My FileSystemWatcher isn't throwing any events. I've looked at these similar questions, none seem to be an answer for my problem:

*Edit: My goal is to capture when an XLS file is copied to or created in a directory.

- [Filesystemwatcher doesn't trigger event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11702993/filesystemwatcher-doesnt-trigger-event)
- [FileSystemWatcher - event not firing the second time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4541522/filesystemwatcher-event-not-firing-the-second-time)
- [FileSystemWatcher Changed event doesn't fire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13887709/filesystemwatcher-changed-event-doesnt-fire)
- [FileSystemWatcher - only the change event once firing once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313942/filesystemwatcher-only-the-change-event-once-firing-once)

Monitor class:

```
public class Monitor
{
    FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
    readonly string bookedPath = @"\\SomeServer\SomeFolder\";

    public delegate void FileDroppedEvent(string FullPath);
    public event FileDroppedEvent FileDropped;

    public delegate void ErrorEvent(Exception ex);
    public event ErrorEvent Error;

    public Monitor()
    {
        watcher.Path = bookedPath;
        watcher.Filter = "*.xls";
        watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite;
        watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(watcher_Changed);
        watcher.Error += new ErrorEventHandler(watcher_Error);
    }

    void watcher_Error(object sender, ErrorEventArgs e)
    {
        Error(e.GetException());
    }

    void watcher_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ChangeType != WatcherChangeTypes.Created) return;
        FileDropped(e.FullPath);
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
    }
}
```

Simple form with Listbox:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Monitor monitor = new Monitor();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        FormClosing += new FormClosingEventHandler(Form1_FormClosing);
        Load += new EventHandler(Form1_Load);
        monitor.FileDropped += new Monitor.FileDroppedEvent(monitor_FileDropped);
        monitor.Error += new Monitor.ErrorEvent(monitor_Error);
    }

    void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        monitor.Start();
    }

    void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        monitor.Stop();
    }

    void monitor_Error(Exception ex)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(ex.Message);
    }

    void monitor_FileDropped(string FullPath)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(FullPath);
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does the user the code is running as have access to the network path?

Comment: Yes. I'm running it and I have access

Comment: You might find the following thread useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11219373/filesystemwatcher-to-watch-unc-path

Comment: Does it work with a non-network path?

Comment: You're only looking for `XLS` files and only monitoring when the file name changes. Is this correct or did you inadvertently limit your filters in testing? If you want to catch events other than when the file name changes, declare more `NotifyFilter`s

Comment: I'll test on a non-network path. But I do need to get it to work on the network path eventually, even if I don't use FileSystemWatcher. TyCobb, originally I had LastAccess not FileName, I made the edit, but you must have got in before I edited it. At any rate, I tried renaming an XLS file and it didn't fire anyway.

Comment: Cameron, comfirmed it's not firing on a local path either

Comment: I think you need to add NotifyFilters.LastWrite or NotifyFilters.CreationTime

Comment: Put a breakpoint on `watcher_Changed`.  I think it may be returning straight away because of `if (e.ChangeType != WatcherChangeTypes.Created) return;`

Comment: Edin, good point. I tried LastWrite, copied a file over. No events.
CodeCaster, I'm not sure where the problem is. I was trying to be helpful by providing the details. If you don't want to follow the method calls you don't have to.
PeteGo - tried that, doesn't fire

Comment: Have you tried `NotifyFilters.FileName`?

Comment: Yes I tried that PeteGO, someone above said that only fires when a filename is changed.

Comment: What's your specific goal?

Comment: Derek W, I want an event to fire when an XLS file is copied to a directory. I'll add that to my original post

Comment: Listen for all events and see what is fired. Or start with [process monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) and see what events are actually fired when operation you are interested in happens. Often simple thing like "create" are not that simple (i.e. create "foo.~temp" and rename to "foo.realExt")

Comment: The very first event that should fire when an xls file is created in the directory is watcher_Changed, I set a breakpoint on that and it never happens. I'm 100% confident the form_load fires (tested with a breakpoint), stepped through the Start(), the code fires sets EnableRaisingEvents to true.

Comment: Why do you think the Changed event would fire, not the Created event?

Comment: even why i try both, it never fires:
watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(watcher_Changed);
watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(watcher_Changed);

Answer (score 2):

Try this out. Works for me for a very similar task.

```
watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.FileName;   
watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(handler);     
watcher.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(handler);
```

Comment: Tried that out, copied a file into the directory. Nothing fired off. I set a breakpoint in the event of the watcher_change event too so it's not an issue with my custom events. Thanks though

Answer (score 0):

This may be because the file metadata hasn't been updated yet. This may happen if you are continuously writing to the file.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following:

```
watcher.Path = directory name;
watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite;
watcher.Filter = "*.xls";

watcher.Changed += OnDirectoryChange;
watcher.Error += OnError;
watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

// Watch only files not subdirectories.
watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = false;
```

Answer (score -1):

Your issue is with the filters as well as your events I believe. `NotifyFilters.LastAccess` will only trigger when a file is opened. Try using:

```
NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.CreationTime
```

This will watch for written/created files. Next, hook up to the `Created` delegate to handle newly created files:

```
watcher.Created += YourDelegateToHandleCreatedFiles
```

The way `FileSystemWatcher` works is to first use the `NotifyFilters` to limit the event triggers. Then, you use the actual events to do the work. By hooking into the `Created` event you'll only do work when a file is created.

Comment: I'll try this, but I really only want to capture when a new file is either created or copied to the directory.

Comment: Then you only want to listen for `NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.CreationTime`

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it still didn't fire :/

Comment: @DontFretBrett I updated it substantially. It was incomplete before. Note the `Created` event.

Comment: Ok tried with LastWrite / CreationTime, handled the Created event, copied a file into the directory, no event. Saved a new XLS into the directory, nothing.

Comment: Did you hook into the `Created` event?